# Redirect to https on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am a bit confused on how to enforce https traffic and also redirect to https. I'm using k8s, kube-lego to issue certificates and is hosted on GCE.

Is there some way to configure the GCE LBs to redirect traffic or some other solution. It is confusing, because there doesn't seem to be an easy solution for this.

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LB for HTTPS in section Network services -> Load balancing -> Create load balancer
Choose the option HTTP(S) Load Balancing and configure it.
For example, you can create load balancer for HTTPS traffic to your frontend.
For more details on how it works, you can read in [Google Cloud Documentations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/)